# Rails 3 + Devise + Angular.js = When I send a post request with angular.js rails lost the current_session object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I'm trying to use Rails 3 + Angular.js, but when I try to send a post request with angular.js to Rails, the controller lost the current_session.

This is the workflow through my application.

**1. Login with devise (Only use the rails way)**

**2. The application is redirect to crear_perfil.html (This is an angular.js view)**

This is my app.js

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-touch
//= require_tree ./angular/models
//= require_tree ./angular/controllers
//= require_tree ./angular/directives
//= require underscore-min
//= require angular-google-maps.min

app = angular.module('squapeApp', ['ngAnimate' , 'ngRoute', 'ngResource','PublicationService','PersonService','appCtrl', 'google-maps', 'ngTouch']);

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', 
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.
        when('/publicaciones',{
            templateUrl: '../assets/index.html',
            controller: 'PublicationCtrl'
        }).
        when('/informacion/perfil',{
            templateUrl: '../assets/crear_perfil.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/publicaciones'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

And this is my angular view for this step:

```
<form name="profileForm" ng-submit="profileForm.$valid && submitForm()" novalidate>
 <input class="text input" type="text" placeholder="Nelson Patricio" id="nombre" ng-model="person.name" required/>
 <input type="submit" name="" value="Guardar" ng-disabled="profileForm.$invalid">
</form>
```

**3. Fill out the field and submit the form to angular.js controller (
    ProfileCtrl )**

This is my appCtrl.js (this file content my ProfileCtrl )

```
var app = angular.module("appCtrl", []);

app.controller('ProfileCtrl', ['Person','$scope','$http', function(Person, $scope, $http){
  $scope.angularClass = "e-profile";
  $scope.person = new Person();
  $scope.persona = Person.query();

  $scope.submitForm = function(){
    if ($scope.profileForm.$valid) {
      console.log("waiting for save");
      $scope.person.$save();
      console.log("save it");
    }
  };

}]);
```

**4. The ProfileCtrl call the Person factory**

```
var person = angular.module('PersonService', []);

person.factory('Person', ['$resource', function($resource){

    var Person = $resource(
    'http://squape.dev/perfil/:id.json', 
    {id: '@id'}, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        },
        query:{
            isArray: false
        }
    });



    return Person;

}]);
```

**5. The Person Factory call the rails controller (ProfileController)**

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json  

  def index
    @person = current_user.person
    respond_with @person
  end

  def create
    @person = current_user.build_person(params[:person])
    if @person.save
      respond_with @person, location: root_path
    end
  end

  def update
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def informacion
    @user = current_user
    @user.build_person if @user.person.nil?
  end
end
```

When I send the angularjs FORM (angularjs send a POST request so the create method is called in the rails controller) my curren_session is nil, but if a I call the angular query method (angularjs send a GET request so the index method is called in the rails controller) the current_user is a good object.

**Why the create method in rails controller return a current_user = nil when I send a POST request ?**

I really appreciate your advice.

regards,

**UPDATE *********

The problem is solved, the current_user is nil because I'm not sending X-CSRF-Token, for solved this in my app.js add this.

> $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] =
>   $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');

```
app = angular.module('squapeApp', ['ngAnimate' , 'ngRoute', 'ngResource','PublicationService','PersonService','appCtrl', 'google-maps', 'ngTouch']);

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', 
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider, $httpProvider){

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');

        $routeProvider.
        when('/publicaciones',{
            templateUrl: '../assets/index.html',
            controller: 'PublicationCtrl'
        }).
        when('/informacion/perfil',{
            templateUrl: '../assets/crear_perfil.html',
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/publicaciones'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

but now the controller create a void object. For any reason isn't receiving the name and the last_name

[image]

Comment: I guess its because you dont send the authenticity token

Comment: Thanks a lot, I add X-CSRF-Token and the POST request is accepted, but now I have problems with the params in the controller. The controller is creating nil object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CSRF token is missing and cause this problem. I recommend to use [`ng-rails-csrf`](https://github.com/xrd/ng-rails-csrf) gem to do it for you.